# Прорисовка SVG-элементов c привязкой к прокрутке страницы в границах видимости определенного блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, анимация, svg-animation

На основе вопроса: [Прорисовка SVG-элементов c привязкой к прокрутке страницы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1271702/377637)

У меня есть следующий SVG-элемент, анимация прорисовки которого запускается с привязкой к прокрутке всей страницы документа:

```js
let p = document.getElementById('path');
let pl = p.getTotalLength();
p.style.strokeDasharray = pl; p.style.strokeDashoffset = pl; 
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  let scrollTo = $(window).scrollTop() /
  (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  draw = pl * scrollTo;
  p.style.strokeDashoffset = pl - draw;
})
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}

.header, .footer {height: 150vh; background: chocolate;}

.parallax {height: 5000px; background: gold;}

#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header"></div>

<div class="parallax">
<!--котейка-->
<svg id="svg" width="500px" height="200px" viewBox="150 0 1 150">

<path id="path" d="M154.5,2.4c0,0,5.5,8.6,2.9,17.5l-1.1-3.4c0,0,0.1,21.1-8.6,26.2l0-4.3c0,0-7.5,22.9-26.8,13.8  C117.2,39.6,110,30.6,99.1,26c-3.8-2.1-8.3-3.2-13.6-3.2c-4.1-0.3-8.4-0.3-13.2,0.3c-22.5,2.6-41.6,20.1-39.4,52  c0.1,0.8,0.2,1.9,0.3,3c-1.5,0.6-3,1.2-4.5,2l-9-10.4l-4.6,16.6L1,87.5l7.8,9.2l-6.3,0.4c0,0,6.4,10.8,10.5,14.2  c11,8.9,21.8,11.5,31.7,10.7c1.5,4.1,3,7.8,4.5,10.8c-3.6-3.6-4.9,2.6-2.3,5.2c1-0.3,1.6,0,2.6-1c1.3,3.3,3.3,2,3.9-0.6  c5.5,6.3,4.6-9.1-0.3-3.6c-1.1-4-1.9-7.9-2.5-11.8c1.4-0.3,2.8-0.7,4.1-1.1c1.4,4.4,2.9,8.5,4.4,11.8c-1.8,0.2-2.1,4.3-0.1,6.3  c1-0.3,1.6,0,2.6-1c1.3,3.3,3.3,2,3.9-0.6c5.5,6.3,4.6-9.1-0.3-3.6l-2,0c-1.2-5.2-2.1-10.3-2.8-15.1c17.9-8,30.1-24.3,30.1-24.3  l-7.4-0.5l10.1-7L75,82.9l0.5-16l-13.9,9.9c2-6.7,5.1-11.4,9.1-13.6c4.5-1.6,9.4-1.4,14.6,1.1c2.9,1.6,5.9,3.9,9.1,7.1  c14.5,17.9,0.4,52-3.9,61.5l0,0c-3.6-3.6-4.9,2.6-2.3,5.2c1-0.3,1.6,0,2.6-1c1.3,3.3,3.3,2,3.9-0.6c5.4,6.2,4.6-8.6-0.1-3.8  c4.6-6.4,9.1-12.8,13.2-19.2c-1.1,6.2-2.9,12.3-5.6,17.9c-3-2-3.9,3.5-1.5,5.9c1-0.3,1.6,0,2.6-1c1.3,3.3,3.3,2,3.9-0.6  c5.5,6.3,4.6-9.1-0.3-3.6l-0.2,0c2.8-6.3,10-23.9,13-42.3c3.5-10,4.9-20.1,3-30.5c5,3.3,12.8,5.4,23.9,0l-3.6-0.7  c0,0,18.4-1.7,22-16.2l-3,2.1C161.9,44.4,176.7,20.6,154.5,2.4z"/>

<!--глазки-->
<path d="M40.5,107.1c0,0-1.9-8.5-8.4-13.3c-0.4-2.5-1-4.1-1.7-4.1c-0.5,0-1,0.9-1.3,2.3c-1.7-0.8-3.6-1.3-5.8-1.4  c0,0-5.7,6.1-1.3,12.4c1.6,2.3,4.4,3.4,7.3,4c0.3,0.9,0.7,1.4,1.1,1.4c0.3,0,0.7-0.4,0.9-1.1C36,107.8,40.5,107.1,40.5,107.1z"/>
<path d="M68.1,86.2c-2.4,0.4-4.4,1.3-6.1,2.4c-0.7-1.4-1.5-2.2-2-2c-0.6,0.2-0.8,1.8-0.6,4.1 c-5.9,5.6-7.2,14.3-7.2,14.3s6,0.3,11.3-1.4c0.5,0.8,1,1.2,1.4,1.1c0.4-0.1,0.6-0.8,0.7-1.9c1.9-0.9,3.6-2.2,4.6-3.9 C73.8,92,68.1,86.2,68.1,86.2z"/>

</svg>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

**Вопрос:** Как запустить анимацию прорисовки SVG-элемента с привязкой к прокрутке страницы, но в границах видимости блока `.parallax`? Начинаться анимация прорисовки элемента должна, когда верхняя часть блока `.parallax` касается верхней части окна браузера. Заканчиваться анимация должна, когда нижняя часть блока `.parallax` касается нижней части окна браузера.

Интересует подробное описание такой реализации и сама реализация любыми средствами и технологиями, указанными в метках вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bместо `htmlElement.scrollTop`, как в другом вопросе, используем `parallax.getBoundingClientRect()` в установленных границах окна просмотра.

```js
const htmlElem = document.querySelector('html')
const parallax = document.querySelector('.parallax')
const path = document.querySelector('#path')
const pathLength = path.getTotalLength()
path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength
path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength

function rangeCalculator(begin, end, beginRange = 0, endRange = 100) {
  const inputRange = end - begin
  const outRange = endRange - beginRange
  return (current) => (
    beginRange + (outRange / (inputRange / (current - begin)))
  )
}

const calculate = (() => {
  let calc
  const remake = () => calc = rangeCalculator(0, parallax.getBoundingClientRect().height - htmlElem.clientHeight, 0, pathLength)
  window.addEventListener('resize', remake)
  remake()
  return () => {
    const { top, bottom } = parallax.getBoundingClientRect()

    // ... когда parallax не достиг верха, это всегда 0
    if (top >= 0) {
      return 0
    }
    // ... а когда коснется низа, это всегда pathLength
    if (bottom <= htmlElem.clientHeight) {
      return pathLength
    }
    // инвертируем знак, так как у нас parallax.top отрицательный, когда он выше границы
    return calc(-top)
  }
})()

document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - calculate()
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header,
.footer {
  height: 150vh;
  background: chocolate;
}

.parallax {
  height: 5000px;
  background: gold;
}

#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>

<div class="parallax">
  <!--котейка-->
  <svg id="svg" width="500px" height="200px" viewBox="150 0 1 150">

      <path id="path"
        d="M154.5,2.4c0,0,5.5,8.6,2.9,17.5l-1.1-3.4c0,0,0.1,21.1-8.6,26.2l0-4.3c0,0-7.5,22.9-26.8,13.8  C117.2,39.6,110,30.6,99.1,26c-3.8-2.1-8.3-3.2-13.6-3.2c-4.1-0.3-8.4-0.3-13.2,0.3c-22.5,2.6-41.6,20.1-39.4,52  c0.1,0.8,0.2,1.9,0.3,3c-1.5,0.6-3,1.2-4.5,2l-9-10.4l-4.6,16.6L1,87.5l7.8,9.2l-6.3,0.4c0,0,6.4,10.8,10.5,14.2  c11,8.9,21.8,11.5,31.7,10.7c1.5,4.1,3,7.8,4.5,10.8c-3.6-3.6-4.9,2.6-2.3,5.2c1-0.3,1.6,0,2.6-1c1.3,3.3,3.3,2,3.9-0.6  c5.5,6.3,4.6-9.1-0.3-3.6c-1.1-4-1.9-7.9-2.5-11.8c1.4-0.3,2.8-0.7,4.1-1.1c1.4,4.4,2.9,8.5,4.4,11.8c-1.8,0.2-2.1,4.3-0.1,6.3  c1-0.3,1.6,0,2.6-1c1.3,3.3,3.3,2,3.9-0.6c5.5,6.3,4.6-9.1-0.3-3.6l-2,0c-1.2-5.2-2.1-10.3-2.8-15.1c17.9-8,30.1-24.3,30.1-24.3  l-7.4-0.5l10.1-7L75,82.9l0.5-16l-13.9,9.9c2-6.7,5.1-11.4,9.1-13.6c4.5-1.6,9.4-1.4,14.6,1.1c2.9,1.6,5.9,3.9,9.1,7.1  c14.5,17.9,0.4,52-3.9,61.5l0,0c-3.6-3.6-4.9,2.6-2.3,5.2c1-0.3,1.6,0,2.6-1c1.3,3.3,3.3,2,3.9-0.6c5.4,6.2,4.6-8.6-0.1-3.8  c4.6-6.4,9.1-12.8,13.2-19.2c-1.1,6.2-2.9,12.3-5.6,17.9c-3-2-3.9,3.5-1.5,5.9c1-0.3,1.6,0,2.6-1c1.3,3.3,3.3,2,3.9-0.6  c5.5,6.3,4.6-9.1-0.3-3.6l-0.2,0c2.8-6.3,10-23.9,13-42.3c3.5-10,4.9-20.1,3-30.5c5,3.3,12.8,5.4,23.9,0l-3.6-0.7  c0,0,18.4-1.7,22-16.2l-3,2.1C161.9,44.4,176.7,20.6,154.5,2.4z" />

      <!--глазки-->
      <path
        d="M40.5,107.1c0,0-1.9-8.5-8.4-13.3c-0.4-2.5-1-4.1-1.7-4.1c-0.5,0-1,0.9-1.3,2.3c-1.7-0.8-3.6-1.3-5.8-1.4  c0,0-5.7,6.1-1.3,12.4c1.6,2.3,4.4,3.4,7.3,4c0.3,0.9,0.7,1.4,1.1,1.4c0.3,0,0.7-0.4,0.9-1.1C36,107.8,40.5,107.1,40.5,107.1z" />
      <path
        d="M68.1,86.2c-2.4,0.4-4.4,1.3-6.1,2.4c-0.7-1.4-1.5-2.2-2-2c-0.6,0.2-0.8,1.8-0.6,4.1 c-5.9,5.6-7.2,14.3-7.2,14.3s6,0.3,11.3-1.4c0.5,0.8,1,1.2,1.4,1.1c0.4-0.1,0.6-0.8,0.7-1.9c1.9-0.9,3.6-2.2,4.6-3.9 C73.8,92,68.1,86.2,68.1,86.2z" />

    </svg>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```